# Firestore: Unable to read document data (Uncaught TypeError: docSnap.exists is not a function at HTMLFormElement)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am a new developer with no experience in Web apps. I have a collection called "users" in Firestore in which the document IDs are the user's emails. I am trying to read the data in one of the documents following the example provided by Firebase [here](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/2b9c3212d3844d394f8d98f30cadc03fdef8c2f5/snippets/firestore-next/test-firestore/get_document.js#L8-L18)

I get two errors:

- First one is the use of "await": *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word*.
- Second is this message: *Uncaught TypeError: docSnap.exists is not a function
  at HTMLFormElement.*

I bypassed the first one by ommiting "await", but cannot avoid the second. Have you got any idea of what is wrong with my code?

console.log(docSnap) gives the following message: "Promise {pending}"

Thanks.

```js
requestForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

const user = auth.currentUser;
const docSnap = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", user.email));

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
        console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
        } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
})
```

Comment: Try `console.log(docSnap)`. I think the promise is not resolved

Comment: Can you share the complete function? Is it an async function or no?

Comment: await can only be used in the context of an async function. The event listener isn't.

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV You are right: console.log(docSnap) gives "Promise {<pending>}"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you return a `Promise` and it does not meet the requirements of `async/await`. Try this way.

```
getDoc(doc(db, "users", user.email)).then(docSnap => {
  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
})
```

Comment: It works! You saved my day! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 4):

Be careful, **getDoc** vs **getDocs**

For single document

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
  console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```

For all document

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "cities"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not work, the same code works some times and others it does not.  I am guessing it has to do with initializeApp that can't be run twice.  It's frustrating.  It carries from back in the day, you might have to check if it already initialized